# Remove files from a NetBeans project but not the hard drive

Tags: netbeans-7.3

I saw the question with an almost identical title, but I want to remove items *after* they were added to the project, without outright deleting them. Is this possible? Netbeans 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Solution working with Netbeans 7.3.1:

right click on your project in the "Projects" window,
click on "Properties",
click on "Ignored folders" in the left panel called "Categories",
click on "Add folder" and select the folders you want to ignore.

Comment: "Ignored folders" doesn't exist in that categories tree. It's on the right under general, but it seems to be using regex, which I am unfamiliar with.